# $_Session variables problems while setting value

Tags: php, session, session-variables

i am creating a shopping cart application but there is a problem while testing $_Session['cart'][$product_ID] its is not setting the values according to the $action variable that i called from a url query from a previous page when I activate query for any of the actions the corresponding switch statement is not making any sort of change to Session variable.
code is listed below

```
session_start();
include "db-class.php";
include "functions.php";
$product_ID=$_GET["id"];
$action=$_GET["action"];
$_SESSIONS['cart'][$product_ID]=0;

/////////// testing session variable and action at start/////////
echo "<br>SESSION VAR BEFORE ACTION=".$_SESSIONS['cart'][$product_ID];
echo "<br>ACTION TO TAKE= ".$action."<br>";
//////////end initial testing/////////

$productExisits=productExists($product_ID);
if($product_ID && !$productExisits)
{
die("PRODUCT DOESNOT EXIST");
}
                    switch($action)
                    {
                    case "add":
                    $_SESSION['cart'][$product_ID]++;
                    break;

                    case "remove":
                    if($_SESSION['cart'][$product_ID]>0)
                    {
                    $_SESSION['cart'][$product_ID]--;
                    }

                    if($_SESSION['cart'][$product_ID]=0)
                    {
                    unset($_SESSION['cart'][$product_ID]);
                    }
                    break;

case "empty":
unset($_SESSION['cart'][$product_ID]);
break;
}

/////////////// testing session variable after action/////////
if(!isset($_SESSION['cart'][$product_ID]))
{
echo "<br>THE CART IS EMPTY NOW<br>";
}
echo "SESSION ID IS= ".$_SESSIONS['cart'][$product_ID];

?>
```

However i want it to change the variable values every time when i perform certain action

idex.html is

```
<?php
//session_start();

?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<image src="img/b_guitar.jpg" height="100 px" width="270 px" border= "2 px">
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<a href="cart.php?action=add&id=1">add to cart</a> ||<br>
<td>
<a href="cart.php?action=remove&id=1">remove from cart</a> ||<br>
<td>
<a href="cart.php?action=empty&id=1">empty cart</a><br>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why should it change? Every time you call the cart update code you reset the cart quantities at line 6 in your above snippet:

```
$_SESSIONS['cart'][$product_ID]=0;
```

you'll always end up with 0 items in the cart when the code fires up, regardless of what your later code does to change that quantity.

Comment: but when i remove it it throws an error where and how should i declare the session variable in particular code

Comment: check for the value's existence, e.g. `if (!isset($_SESSION[....])) { $_SESSION[...] = 0; }`. only assign it a 0 value if it DOESN'T exist. otherwise you will continue to trash the quantity value.